# how to enable https in my facebook app

Tags: facebook

i created an app and set my web URL which is https://www.mysite.com but i keep getting a message from Facebook's comments plugin in the little yellow box saying "warning: cant find http://www.mysite.com"

the plugin is working great and i can see comments and even share and like.

how can i fix that?

here is a print screen:
[image]

Comment: facebook by default supports https, you don't need to do any configuration

Comment: then how do i solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look to below screen shots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem found. we have a loadbalancer that causes that in the inner server he sees itself as http and in the outer is actually https. i had to manually add the "s" to the output.

thx for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I am adding screen shot of one of my app, you can follow these screen shot:

Make sure to disable Sandbox mode and you should fill required URL as shown below.

[image]

Comment: hide facebook appid and app secret from your screen shot anyone can get access to your app using this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

Comment: i cant find this screen nor the place where i cancel it from being a sandbox sln, any hint?

Comment: I am not able to understand your screen shot due to language, can you change to English?

Comment: not much to translate, it just sais:"warning: cant find http://www.mysite.com", could you put the full url of this page? (cutting personal data o.c.)